# undefined reference to `__gnu_Unwind_Find_exidx'

Tags: android, android-ndk, undefined-reference

My NDK Project Build success only when

```
APP_ABI :=  armeabi armeabi-v7a
```

when I enabled `arm64-v8a` in `Application.mk` for example:

```
APP_ABI :=  armeabi armeabi-v7a arm64-v8a
```

The project will build failed
and show the error

> undefined reference to `__gnu_Unwind_Find_exidx

I am a new starter in android NDK.

code screenshot:
[image]